# Url Rewrite in Self-Hosted environment

Tags: url-rewriting, signalr, owin, reverse-proxy

I have a SignalR-service in two api-versions running in self-hosted Owin processes. I want to route traffic for api.service.com to either api1.service.com or api2.service.com depending on a http-header (api-ver) in a request. Is this possible to do with Owin middleware or in some other way without having to host this in IIS or using a 3rd party reverse proxy or similar? I was hoping it could be done with "Url Rewriting" but I don't know if this is possible in self-hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered this, I am in the same boat and thinking it will resolve my problem.  But to answer your question it does seem possible in self-hosted environments.

[Owin.UrlRewrite](https://github.com/gertjvr/Owin.UrlRewrite)

*EDIT* - This library doesn't work (at least I sure can't get it to work).  I did experiment with an OWIN middleware of my own and it can be done with redirects but there is a flicker in the URL to essentially the hashtag url (before the client router kicks in (Aurelia in my case) and makes it the non-hash url).  Best I can say is this is a limited use case (Self-hosting with need for URL Rewriting) as I cannot find a pre-made solution to do this.